# Why does Arch Linux install applications to root, instead of home folder like other Distros? Is this a security risk?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, security, root

I have recently come to understand that Arch Linux install all applications in /root directory only, while other Distro provide an option to the user to install in /home directory ?

Why is this the case ?

As a followup does this mean that a user security is compromised if malicious software is installed in root and thus had access to the entire OS ? Wouldn't it be better to install application in /home ? Should one worry about this issue ?

Comment: `/root` is root's home directory.  If you compile programs as root and install them in the home dir, that's where they'll go.   If you compile as a user and install in the home dir, they'll go in the user's home dir.    In most cases, however, you're better off just installing the arch package of whatever you're installing (assuming that a package exists) rather than compiling it yourself.

Comment: BTW, the location of a program doesn't really affect system security (although it will probably prevent normal users running software installed under /root because normal users probably don't have access to /root).  What matters is WHO runs it, and what permissions they have. If the program is run as a normal user, it will only have that user's privileges (unless it's a setuid program).

Comment: Which distro installs software to the home directory?

Comment: @eesiraed I'm very sure none of them do. The whole point of a distro is to offer a system installation.

Comment: I wonder if @Sandeep is thinking of Fedora Silverblue and other immutable OSs, where you *can* install software into the home directory using Flatpak and toolbox/distrobox. But even in silverblue, you can layer on RPMs from the fedora repos.

Comment: @cas Many thanks for you detailed explanation. Personally when I install programs from github, I download the the source code to a folder in  /root, CD into that folder and then run makepkg  or ./install.sh inside the folder.
if it is a binary file, then I would simply run pacman -S and let the package manager do the magic. With AUR helper like yay I pretty much follow the same route meaning I am "not" specifying the destination directory.
The security question arose because it may just be possible that you run a source code in root and thus inadvertently give access to some malicious code ?

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks for you reply sir. I presume I should explain myself a bit because I feel I must have probably asked a stupid question. The genesis of my question was from a youtube channel I follow. DistroTube, where DT mentioned that he installs all his package in root because Arch installs all packages in /root. I was perhaps naive of me to assume that other Distros don't necessarily do that. Btw interesting to note that there are **immutable** OS's out there.   thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you got your information.

Arch does *not* install all applications to the `/root` directory. Binaries are in `/usr/local/bin` and  other stuff tends to be put in `/usr/share`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local`, etc. This is perfectly normal. Installing applications that would be used by multiple users in `/home` folder, however, is not.

Comment: "Normal" ? "is not normal" ? Well… I'd say "provide tools not policy"… Best in class *x tools just enable their users to define what is normal and what is not. Package managers are of that kind. They do implement a default policy, because one is needed, but enable their users to define their own. (at their own risks of course… but… isn't this, at the end of the day… the most exciting part of the game ? (from a sysadmin standpoint of course)) ;-)

Comment: @MC68020 policy is at least as important as tools - from a distro dev's point of view anyway. Strong, well-designed  policies are fundamental to strong system.  Also, if you're a sysadmin and think "exciting" is a good thing, you're doing it wrong. A sysadmin's job is to make sure things never get too exciting, it is to make machines run smoothly without fuss and without excitement. Unfortunately, if you do the job well enough, your employers may start to wonder if they ever needed you because things that break get attention, but things that never break become background noise and are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The destination on your system of whatever file included in a package is on the responsibility of the package manager you will be using.
All the package managers I know usually **default** to honoring [standard locations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) with possible differences for some packages (prefer /usr/local to /usr, make differences between /bin and /usr/bin /lib and /usr/lib… or not)

The **default base directory** of this hierarchy (/) **can** be changed in some way depending on the package manager.
*pacman* (default package manager for archlinux) can be launched with the [-r option](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) in order to specify an alternative installation root.

Therefore, if all your packages are installed in /root and you don't want that, ensure that you are not overriding the defaults launching `pacman -r /root`. If you want these packages to be installed in /home, explicitly `pacman -r /home` and if you are happy with standard location then simply resort to default and just don't use the r option.

For security concerns, as [@cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) wrote in comments :

> BTW, the location of a program doesn't really affect system security
> (although it will probably prevent normal users running software
> installed under /root because normal users probably don't have access
> to /root). What matters is WHO runs it, and what permissions they
> have. If the program is run as a normal user, it will only have that
> user's privileges (unless it's a setuid program)

Adding to that the fact that, if you want /root as base dir you'll need to run pacman itself as root and therefore be exposed to all the security implications of running whatever program as root.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. I presume the pacman -r /home flag must be used in special circumstances when you have multiple users who may or may not need access to the same programme.

Comment: @Sandeep : Your comment here as well as the last comment you wrote in the OP make me suspect something : Would you in fact be somehow confusing between *root* (/) and */root* (one directory under /) and between *$HOME* (the variable containing some user's home directory) */home* (some subdir of / base of all users home directories) ?

Comment: Thanks. I presume I was not sure about _XDG Base Directory Specification_ and assumed a lot of things. The future **me** knows this was dumb question, but i don;t know why i assumed packages are installed in / and not ~/$HOME